Android build in React Native CLI consistently fails due to a mismatch between the SDK version and the Gradle version
Whenever I build the React application, it automatically selects version 8.2.1, which is not specified, and also picks the latest SDK version. As a result, the build keeps failing.

Android gradle plugin: 8.2.1 Gradle: 8.0.1 Warning: SDK processing.
This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML
file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions
of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at
different times. WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools
version (33.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported
version (34.0.0) for Android Gradle Plugin 8.2.1. Android SDK Build
Tools 34.0.0 will be used.

/android/build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip
networkTimeout=10000
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


I have updated all the packages, SDK and Gradle to latest version. It worked.
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

If you received this warning in a flutter project. If you get this warning in Android Studio(Maybe there is a solution with similar settings in vs code, and maybe intellij idea also has a similar solution), apply the suggested Android versions on (etc.build.gradles) by clicking on the yellow underlined codes in the configuration settings and the suggested light. Then search for the "flutter clean" item in the properties in the lower left corner and run it (it may be somewhere else, I don't remember exactly). Then click "sync now" in the logcat section to finish the fixes. After these operations, the warning should no longer appear. Of course, this was just a solution for me.
